# Oracle DB 12c can't start tns service

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Yesterday I restarted my machine and now my DB is unavailable.
I had already some difficulties to run it the first time because there were two different installations of Oracle DB.

The windows services that I suppose they should run:

- OracleJobSchedulerFOOBAR
- OracleOraDB12Home3MTSRecoveryService
- OracleOraDB12Home3TNSListener : **OracleOraDB12Home3TNSListener service on your local computer start and stopped. Some service stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs**.
- OracleServiceFOOBAR
- OracleVssWriterFOOBAR

So as you can see : I can not start the OracleOraDB12Home3TNSListener service.

I changed  the file tnsnames.ora :

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )


  FOOBAR=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myurl.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = FOOBAR)
    )
  )
```

And my listener.ora is

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\OracleDB\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\OracleDB\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myurl.com)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

I already try a lot of things like :

- `sqlplus / as sysdba` and `startup` but I got

ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER
ORA-00132: syntax error or unresolved network name 'LISTENER_FOOBAR'

- `alter system set local_listener='FOOBAR';  scope=spflile;` but I got

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

When I check I the Oracle Administration Assistance for the OracleDB12Home3 :

- ORACLE_SDI = FOOBAR
- ORACLE_HOME = C:\OracleDB\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1

Does someone has any idea on how to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long investigations, thanks the help of a colleague, it's working.

To sum up how we did to solve it :

- So to fix my first issue 'OracleOraDB12Home3TNSListener can not start' was due to that I had a new IP. So I changed it in my config (...\NETWORK\ADMIN
  ): https://community.oracle.com/thread/855326
- when I was trying to connect with *sql developer* (after the restart of my computer). I had the error: *ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist*. That was meaning that my DB was not started (http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_01034_oracle_not_available.htm).
- So I try start the db manually `sqlplus / as sysdba` and `startup` but I had always this output :

  SQL> startup
  ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER
  ORA-00132: syntax error or unresolved network name 'LISTENER_FOOBAR'
- To fix I tried to work on the *LISTENER.ORA* and *TNSNAMES.ORA* files :

LISTENER.ORA

---

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\OracleDB\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\OracleDB\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME=FOOBAR)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\OracleDB\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = FOOBAR)
    )
  )

LISTENER_FOOBAR =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =  localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

TNSNAMES.ORA

---

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )


FOOBAR =
 (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =  localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = FOOBAR)
    )
  )
```

- I try to restart the right windows service several times : OracleServiceFOOBAR but nothing was changing.  I had always the same issue. I remember that I did pfile configuration.
- So I decided to change the pfile configuration with something like alter system set LOCAL_LISTENER='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))' scope=both;. Right but I can't apply any command line because the database don't start...
- so i created a pfile called init.ora with *.local_listener='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))' trick from [ORA-00119: invalid specification ORA-00132: syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28765999/ora-00119-invalid-specification-ora-00132-syntax-error). And I started the DB wit this file in parameter `SQL> startup pfile=c:\oracledb\admin\XXX\pfile\init.ora`

And then it was working.